# SVG styling of text with NVD3 library

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I have created a very simple chart with NVD3.js as can be seen on [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/El4a/4huxnmzt/)

The problem lies with the title (text in the middle) which consists of a number and a symbol (%).

I need both those parts to be styled separate but this seems to be a real pain.

I have discovered I can only style an SVG through inline style tags so I already applied :

```
<div id="svgDiv"><svg id="test2" fill='#58B957' letter-spacing='-3px'></svg></div>
```

to get the color and spacing right. **Now I still need the %-symbol to be a lot smaller than the number**. Which I can't apply to the full svg, because this would make everything smaller.

I have tried all manners of adding classes, id's, wrapping them in tspan's etc; yet I can't figure it out.

Please tell me there's a straightforward solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a direct way in nvd3 but you can do this trick to empty the text and fill with tspan.

```
  var text1 = d3.select(".nv-pie-title").text("");//get the title clear it
  text1.append("tspan").attr("class", "number").text("85")//make first tspan
  text1.append("tspan").attr("class", "percent").text("%")//make second tspan
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8p28rj63/)

Comment: Good Lord you are a life savior! (Atleast saved the life of my pc who was very close to soaring through the window!) Thanks very much!